# Nginx rewrite. Need help to rewrite only 0-9a-z- characters

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have this directive in my nginx virtual host file:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /profile.php?nickname=$uri&$args;
```

It works ok, but I want to rewrite only 0-9a-z- characters so that users have nice profile addresses, for example:

```
http://www/mydomain.com/john
```

But nginx rewrites everything. For example, if I enter address:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/non-existing-holder/nonexisting-filename.html
```

instead of returning 404 error it rewrites everything.

Is there any way how to rewrite only 0-9-a-z- characters?

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root /var/www/mydomain;
    error_page 404 /4044.html;
    location / {
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /profile.php?nickname=$uri&$args;
        rewrite ^/forum/([0-9-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+).html$ /forum.php?tid=$1&title=$2 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files  $uri =404;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand the `try_files` portion of your location / block. `try_files $uri $uri/ /profile.php...$args;` will try to find files that actually exist first, then pass the URI to `profile.php`. This is why you don't get a 404. Your `profile.php` would have to do the 404 handling. It is also why the rewrite rule never runs... because the URI gets sent to `profile.php` and no longer matches the rewrite rule.

Comment: @Brendan Please send it as an answer so it can be operated with further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following configuration.

- Request for /testUSER would return a 404
- Request for /forum/100/something.html would go to /forum.php?tid=100&title=something
- Request for /nickname would go to /profile.php?nickname=nickname

.

```
location / {
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    rewrite ^/([0-9a-z-]+)/?$ /profile.php?nickname=$1&$args last;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
location /forum {
    rewrite ^/forum/([0-9-]+)/([0-9a-z-]+).html$ /forum.php?tid=$1&title=$2 last;
    alias /var/www/mydomain/forum;
}
```

Comment: Igor, I tried this but nging rewrites existing directories, for example: http://www.mydomain.com/forum/ (existing directory) rewrites to profile.php?nickname=forum. http://www.mydomaim.com/forum/subdirectory/ works OK.

Comment: Unfortunately if you have custom directories in your root directory, you're just going to have to list them. You can't have it both ways if I believe. You can either have dynamic nicknames or dynamic directories. I added another location so try this.

Comment: I have many costom directories (12), so maybe it´s better to leave it without changes so that nginx rewrites any characters if directory doesnt exist. I hope it will not cause any other problems.